# Редактирование SWF: добавление ссылки

Tags: actionscript

Доброго всем здравия.
Есть SWF, есть декомпиляторы
swix + "Sothink SWF Decompiler"
Просто необходимо добавить линьк.
Первое ПО вообще показывает только xml
Вторая показывает скрипт, НО как туда прописать\дописать свой (переход по ссылке) и сохранить опять же в swf?

P.S. Sothink, даёт только экспортировать в HTML+FLA.
Обязательна ли ПОКУПКА (!?) Adobe Flash редактора?
Нужно-то всего дописать ссылку.

Comment: Если я не ошибаюс, то декомпиляторы не позволяют изменять внутреннее содержимое. Хотя может быть я ошибаюсь и они таки позволяют заменить необходимые ресурсы.

Comment: Нашёл Adobe Flash, выбрал область (она первая, скорее всего с альфапрозрачностью), 
ели нашёл, как вставить скрипт.
  
Но скомпилировав результата НОЛЬ:  

    shape 1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoURL);  
    function gotoURL(event:MouseEvent):void {  
     var URL:URLRequest=new URLRequest("http://ru");  
     navigateToURL(URL);  
    }